# Colors from array

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Trying use colors from my array in List.generate, i have only 4 colors, each new one must use the color from the first in array:

```
var colorList = [Color(0xFF0057ff42), Color(0xFFffad3142), Color(0xFF2ed1b442), Color(0xFF00c6ff42)];
GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: List.generate(10, (index) {
        return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Stack(
                children: < Widget > [
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), offset: Offset(0, 3), blurRadius: 7),
                            ],
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                            'Игры',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: const Color(0xFF4F4F4F),
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0.0,
                        right: 0.0,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: null,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            disabledColor: colorList[index],
                            child: Icon(
                                Icons.camera_alt,
                                size: 40,
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                            shape: CircleBorder(),
                        )
                    )
                ]
            )
        );
    })
),
```

I get the error:

> "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..3: 4"

I know it's because of the number of colors, i have only 4 but in my list have 10.
How else can you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat the colors using [modulo operator (%)](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/double/operator_modulo.html) like this.

```
disabledColor: colorList[index % colorList.length],
```

Comment: Error: The getter 'colorsList' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'.

Comment: U have error colorList not colorsList, its work only every 2

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I have edited the answer. Try now.

Comment: @Elexer, it looks like it works only every 2 because 2 colors in the list have opacity 0, so they are not seen.

Comment: Thank you for edit. But its not what i need, I need use colors in array for every item, colors only 4, if list item #5 need use array from start

Comment: That is exactly what this will do.

Comment: Oh my god, you're right, 2 colors have opacity, fixed and its work, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

var colorList = [Color(0xFF0057ff42), Color(0xFFffad3142), Color(0xFF2ed1b442), Color(0xFF00c6ff42)];
GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: List.generate(10, (index) {
        return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Stack(
                children: < Widget > [
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), offset: Offset(0, 3), blurRadius: 7),
                            ],
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                            'Игры',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: const Color(0xFF4F4F4F),
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0.0,
                        right: 0.0,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: null,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            disabledColor: colorList[Random().nextInt(colorList.length)],
                            child: Icon(
                                Icons.camera_alt,
                                size: 40,
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                            shape: CircleBorder(),
                        )
                    )
                ]
            )
        );
    })
),
```

It seems like you want to use random colors for each new item.

use this if you want to assign a random color to each new item:

```
Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);
```

make sure you have imported this

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
```

Try this code if you want to assign a random color:

```
GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: List.generate(10, (index) {

          Color pickColor = Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);

        return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Stack(
                children: < Widget > [
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), offset: Offset(0, 3), blurRadius: 7),
                            ],
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                            'Игры',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: const Color(0xFF4F4F4F),
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0.0,
                        right: 0.0,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: null,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            disabledColor: pickColor,
                            child: Icon(
                                Icons.camera_alt,
                                size: 40,
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                            shape: CircleBorder(),
                        )
                    )
                ]
            )
        );
    })
),
```

Comment: I no need random color, only in my array, each new one must use the color from the first in array. Trying your code, get error Error: The method 'Random' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'.

Comment: I Added two type of code. first one is according to your need and the second one is random color picker. Must Import ```import 'dart:math' as math;``` this. otherwise you will get errror